# Android Cordova index.html not found but it has been loaded in the backgroud

Tags: android, cordova

I have a kinda weired problem. I startet a cordova project and everything went fine. Even running the app on an actual device did not spit up any issues.

Now I tried to run the applicatio in the android emulator. Now I'm getting the message that the index.htm could not be found. *But* if I wait for a few seconds the index.htm is loaded properly and is shown behind the 'index.htm not found' messagebox.
I added a screenshot to show you what I mean.

[Android emulatior screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKuUQ.png)

This is my current folder structure:

```
App/
    hooks/
    platforms/
    plugins/
    resources/
    www/
        index.htm
    config.xml
```

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: it should be index.html, not index.htm, not sure if it's a typo, but you wrote it wrong a lot of times

Answer (score 0):

your actual path is here

**App Name\platforms\android\assets\www**

in this www index.html main file is here what aver you will write it's reflect in your app.

Comment: On build cordova moves the files from www/ to platforms/android/assets/www so it is there and afterall it is shown behind the messagebox if you take a look at the screenshot

Comment: yes so you will be modify  platforms\android\assets\www .. inside index.html

Comment: Ok the file wich is missing is platforms/android/platform_www/index.html. But why does cordova use the .../android/www folder instead of  the .../android/platform_www folder?